# How to change layout of pre-configured site in AEM 6

Tags: osgi, aem, sling, crx

I am trying to change the layout and customize the pre-configured Geometrixx-Gov site in AEM 6. For example, I would like to change the blue color in the header

[image]

Also, I would like to change the text of `All Applications` to something else I want.

**Questions**

- What is the best way to make these changes?
- Once I make my changes, is there a way to somehow take/package my changes and deploy them to an instance of AEM not running on my local computer?

When I try to edit things, I can change the text around in the body of the site but can't seem to change the text around in the header

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- To change the menu, I think you have to change the page title or the page navigation title, you probably have a page called "All Applications".

2- To change the color, you have to edit the CSS in the client libs which are somewhere under /etc/clientlibs/{your_app}

3- You can package the application using the package manager, make sure you include the /apps/{your_app}, /etc/clientlibs/{your_app}, /etc/designs/{your_app}, /content/{your_app}, those are basic folders, you may need other files or paths in your filters, make sure all dependencies are respected.